# OpenManage: how to update systems?

Tags: dell-openmanage

Are there components beyond the base installation for OMSA required if you want to use the system to update other servers? I found the .ISO for 'SUU' which definitely didn't get included in the original installation.

As it stands I can't do any of the 'recommended updates' that OMSA points out. I get failures on every attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me what you're asking but I'll give it a shot:

Q: Can you use OMSA to update other Dell servers?

A: Not to my knowledge. OMSA is the "managed node" component of OpenManage. It is not the "management node" of OpenManage.

Q: Well then what do I need to manage other servers?

A: You need Dell OpenManage Essentials and/or Dell Repository Manager to manage and/or update other Dell servers.

Q: But how can I update just a single server?

A: You can download the appropriate Dell updates CD/DVD or the SUU CD/DVD and use that to update a single server.

Comment: My mistake. I have OpenManage Essentials running on one machine. On my servers I have the 'srvadmin-all' package installed. There is a page in 'essentials' that tells me which machines need which patches. When I try to run these updates via 'essentials' I get consistent failures.

Comment: In any event I tried to install SUU on the VM that I'm using for OM E. Was told 'aborting - this isn't a Dell system'. Alas.

Comment: SUU is for the physical Dell server, not for the VM. The SUU has hardware updates for Dell hardware. The VM does not have Dell hardware it has virtual hardware. DOMSA should be installed on the physical host, not on the VM.

Comment: So SUU needs to be installed on every server?

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page but here's what I'm saying: 1. If you have multiple Dell servers and you want to manage them then you need to install DOMSA on each of them. 2. If you have multiple Dell servers and you want to update them then you need to run the SUU on each of them. 3. DOMSA and SUU are for the physical Dell servers, they are not for the virtual machines running on whatever virtualization platform you have installed on the Dell servers.